# How to count the number of relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j 2.0 and using the following query to find out the count of number of a particular relationship from a particular node.

I have to check the number of relationships named "LIVES" from a particular node PERSON.

My query is:

```
match (p:PERSON)-[r:LIVES]->(u:CITY) where count(r)>1  
return count(p);
```

The error shown is:

```
SyntaxException: Invalid use of aggregating function count(...)
```

How should I correct it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

What you want is a version of having? People living in more than one city?

```
MATCH (p:PERSON)-[:LIVES]->(c:CITY) 
WITH p,count(c) as rels, collect(c) as cities
WHERE rels > 1
RETURN p,cities, rels
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with a complexity where aggregate is not working, any idea any? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841856/neo4j-cypher-query-multiple-aggregates

Comment: this isnt very performant over a large data set...