# Cypher - Return nodes with their relation with a count contraint on the relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

This question is related to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346526/how-to-count-the-number-of-relationships-in-neo4j).

I explain my little usecase to better understand my problem :

I have this kind of graph
`(doc)-[contain]-(sentence)-[with]-(word)`

Nodes (word) can have semantic relations between them `(word)-[rel]-(word)`

I want to return (doc) with a number of [rel] > 10

This query can do that :

```
MATCH (doc:document)-[contain]-(sentence)-[with]-(ng1:word)-[rel:relations]-(ng2:word)
WITH doc, count(rel) as nbRels, collect(rel) as rels
WHERE nbRels > 10 RETURN doc, nbRels, rels
```

But I don't know what (word) are concerned by each [rel] found.

Is it possible to do know and to return that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but you should be able to unwind your `rels` collection and pull out the start and end nodes. Something like:

```
MATCH (doc:document)-[contain]-(sentence)-[with]-(ng1:word)-[rel:relations]-(ng2:word)
WITH doc, count(rel) as nbRels, collect(rel) as rels
WHERE nbRels > 10
WITH doc, UNWIND(rels) as rel,
RETURN doc, STARTNODE(rel), ENDNODE(rel)
```

But you might just want to collect something different in the first place:

```
MATCH (doc:document)-[contain]-(sentence)-[with]-(ng1:word)-[rel:relations]-(ng2:word)
WITH doc, ng1, collect(ng2) as rels
WHERE LENGTH(rels) > 10 
RETURN doc, ng1, rels
```

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you a lot! Your answer helps me a lot.

Here is the query with correct syntax (if you want to edit your answer) 

`MATCH (doc:document {docid:5881})-[contain]-(sentence)-[with]-(ng1:word)-[rel:relations]-(ng2:word)
WITH doc, count(rel) as nbRels, collect(rel) as rels
WHERE nbRels > 10
WITH doc, rels UNWIND rels AS rel
RETURN doc, STARTNODE(rel), ENDNODE(rel)`

Thank you again,