# NEO4J Cypher Query: Multiple Aggregates

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Sample Data

[image]

> Sample Query: At the end of this post

**Objective: Searches similar to 'who knows exactly 2 Cust and works at 1 company'**

---

**Step 1**: I just did a print of the number of connected Cust and Comp and its all good till now

```
MATCH (from:Cust), (a:Cust), (b:Comp),
p1=((from)-[r1]-(a)), p2=((from)-[r2]-(b))
WITH from, count(DISTINCT a) as knows, count(DISTINCT b) as works 
RETURN from.title, knows, works
```

[image]

---

**Step 2**: I went and added WHERE clause to filter the count, so far so good

```
MATCH (from:Cust), (a:Cust), (b:Comp),
p1=((from)-[r1]-(a)), p2=((from)-[r2]-(b))
WITH from, count(DISTINCT a) as knows, count(DISTINCT b) as works 
WHERE knows=2 and works=1
RETURN from.title, knows, works
```

Result > Alpha | 2 | 1

---

**Step 3**: Now I also want some filters on Cust and Comp add a and b to my WITH clause

```
MATCH (from:Cust), (a:Cust), (b:Comp),
p1=((from)-[r1]-(a)), p2=((from)-[r2]-(b))
WITH from, count(DISTINCT a) as knows, count(DISTINCT b) as works, a, b
RETURN from.title, knows, works
```

And BOOM! everything is 1, 1

[image]

It looks aggregate is getting confused with multiple variables in the WITH clause so and start to add multiple WITH clause and UNWIND, but I was unable to get the query for it.

**Sample Data Creation**

```
CREATE (a:Cust {title: "Alpha"})
CREATE (b:Cust {title: "Bravo"})
CREATE (c:Cust {title: "Charlie"})
CREATE (d:Cust {title: "Delta"})

create (g:Comp {title: "Google"})
create (f:Comp {title: "Facebook"})
create (s:Comp {ttile: "Stackoverflow"})

MATCH (a:Cust {title: "Alpha"}), (b:Cust {title: "Bravo"})
CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)

MATCH (a:Cust {title: "Alpha"}), (c:Cust {title: "Charlie"})
CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(c)

MATCH (d:Cust {title: "Delta"}), (c:Cust {title: "Charlie"})
CREATE (d)-[:KNOWS]->(c)

MATCH (c:Cust {title: "Charlie"}), (b:Cust {title: "Bravo"})
CREATE (c)-[:KNOWS]->(b)


MATCH (g:Comp {title: "Google"}), (s:Comp {ttile: "Stackoverflow"})
CREATE (g)-[:USES]->(s)

MATCH (f:Comp {title: "Facebook"}), (s:Comp {ttile: "Stackoverflow"})
CREATE (f)-[:USES]->(s)

MATCH (d:Cust {title: "Delta"}), (s:Comp {ttile: "Stackoverflow"})
CREATE (d)-[:WORKS_AT]->(s)

MATCH (d:Cust {title: "Delta"}), (g:Comp {title: "Google"})
CREATE (d)-[:WORKS_AT]->(g)

MATCH (a:Cust {title: "Alpha"}), (f:Comp {title: "Facebook"})
CREATE (a)-[:WORKS_AT]->(f)

MATCH (c:Cust {title: "Charlie"}), (s:Comp {ttile: "Stackoverflow"})
CREATE (c)-[:WORKS_AT]->(s)
```

Comment: It's unclear what result you want to get with the third query. The query itself works correctly: when you simultaneously use a variable and aggregate on it, you will logically receive one as a result.

Comment: A query that does aggregation BUT also returns all the variables. I want the path variables for my result AND also want to apply filter like atleast 2 connections etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stdob-- says, the aggregation is working correctly. Aggregation in Cypher uses all the non-aggregation variables as the grouping key, which provides context for the aggregation.

In your step 2 query, you have:

```
WITH from, count(DISTINCT a) as knows, count(DISTINCT b) as works
```

`knows` and `works` are both aggregating using `count()`, so `from` is the grouping key...the counts are with respect to each `from` node.

In your step 3 query, you have

```
WITH from, count(DISTINCT a) as knows, count(DISTINCT b) as works, a, b
```

So `from`, `a`, and `b` are the grouping key... so for each row of `from`, a single `a`, and a single `b` node (note that this is a cross product with every `a` and `b` node connected to `from`), you're getting the count of distinct `a` nodes and `b` nodes...which is always going to be 1.

A better approach to get the answer you want (which I can't say with certainty, as you didn't specify what you really wanted to do with `a` and `b` in your query, you didn't use them in your return) is to get the degrees of relationship types from your from node, then collect the connected nodes (or use pattern comprehension to get them in a collection for you).

For example:

```
MATCH (from:Cust)
WITH from, size((from)-[:KNOWS]-()) as knowsDeg, 
     size((from)-[:WORKS_AT]-()) as worksAtDeg, 
     [(from)-[:KNOWS]-(a:Cust) | a] as known, 
     [(from)-[:WORKS_AT]-(b:Comp) | b] as worksAt
RETURN from.title, knowsDeg, worksAtDeg, known, worksAt
```

Also, I should point out that you have cross products in your original query, which is why you needed to use DISTINCT in your count:

```
MATCH (from:Cust), (a:Cust), (b:Comp),
p1=((from)-[r1]-(a)), p2=((from)-[r2]-(b))
WITH from, count(DISTINCT a) as knows, count(DISTINCT b) as works 
RETURN from.title, knows, works
```

If you had left off DISTINCT, the counts for each would have been the same, the product of the number of connected :Cust nodes * the number of connected :Comp nodes. If you only wanted counts (and wanted to get them through expansion rather than by degree as in my answer), you could get them without forming a cross product by collecting them after you match to each like so:

```
MATCH (from:Cust)--(a:Cust)
WITH from, count(a) as knows
MATCH (from)--(b:Comp)
WITH from, knows, count(b) as works
RETURN from.title as title, knows, works
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried and your queries work great, but I have a problem. When I add the **path** variable my counts get messed up, like *MATCH p1=((from:Cust)--(a:Cust))
WITH from, count(a) as knows, p1
MATCH p2=((from)--(b:Comp))
WITH from, knows, count(b) as works, p1, p2
RETURN from.title as title, knows, works, p1, p2*    any idea what should i do if i need the **path** too?

Comment: This is because the context of the aggregation now has to consider the path. In english, your first WITH translates to: Give me the count of `a` nodes for this `from` node and this particular path `p1`. The particular path for each row will only have a single `a` node, so your count will always be 1. You need to keep the context of your aggregation to just `from`, so if you want the paths, you have to collect() them in each step (that way the variable for it won't be part of the grouping key, you'll be back to aggregating with respect to `from` and nothing else)

Comment: To better understand, try returning what you have just after your first WITH, and look at the row results: you have a separate path per row. Pay attention to what's aggregated and what's not. Remember aggregations are with respect to the non-aggregation variables.